# Applying an id attribute based on a variable's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that checks the value of a variable and then applies the correct `id` attribute accordingly. The value of `menuLink` will have the same value of one of the parts of `.mainmenu a` href path name.

Is there a way to simplify this so it can search the href path of `.mainmenu a` instead of explicitly stating each one?

```
if (menuLink == "whatsnew") {
    $('.mainmenu a:eq(1)').attr('id', 'active').addClass("disable");
} else if (menuLink == "products") {
    $('.mainmenu a:eq(2)').attr('id', 'active').addClass("disable");
} else if (menuLink == "contact") {
    $('.mainmenu a:eq(3)').attr('id', 'active').addClass("disable");
} etc.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an array!

And to remember that you can dynamically construct jQuery selectors.

Then you need to loop through the array and search for the matching `menuLink`:

```
var links = ["whatsnew", "products", "contact"];

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (menuLink == links[i]) {
        var jqueryEq = i + 1;
        $('.mainmenu a:eq(' + jqueryEq + ')').attr('id', 'active').addClass("disable");
    }
}
```

However, you might want to consider a significantly simpler approach... what if you give the whatsnew, products and contact a matching id or class? Then the code could be as easy as:

```
$('.mainmenu .' + menuLink).attr('id', 'active').addClass("disable");
```

Comment: The array method works great! Could you explain the simpler approach a bit more?

Comment: @user2867494 It uses string concatenation to add '.mainmenu .' together with the menuLink, so you can use the HTML code `class="whatsnew"` on the "whatsnew" section to mark it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't change IDs. IDs are supposed to identify a specific element, regardless of any state. "Active" should be a class.

The `.mainmenu` class should probably also be an ID. It's the "main menu" - that's its identity. Classes are for when you have multiple elements that are "of the same class", i.e. they share some functionality or styling. (If you have multiple things called "*main* menu", you have other problems.)

Using an `active` class will also let you use the IDs to find the link you want make active.

```
$("#mainmenu a.active").removeClass("active")
$("#" + menulink).addClass("active");
```

Basically: Find the currently active link, and remove the "active" class from it. Then find the link with the ID you're looking for, and set *that* to active by adding the class.

Comment: Excellent point about not changing ids, I didn't even think about that! That's what happens when you read code too quickly...